# Training a Keras model from batches of .npy files using generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Currently I am dealing with a big data issue when training Image data using Keras. I have directory which has batch of .npy file. Each batch contain 512 images. Each batch has its corresponding label file as .npy. So it looks like: {image_file_1.npy, label_file_1.npy, ..., image_file_37.npy, label_file_37}. Each image file has dimension `(512, 199, 199, 3)`, each label file has dimension `(512, 1)`(eather 1 or 0) . If I load all the images in one ndarray it will be 35+ GB. So far reading all the Keras Doc. I am still not able to find how I will be able to train using custom generator. I have read about `flow_from_dict` and `ImageDataGenerator(...).flow()` but they are not ideal in that case or I do not know how to customized them.Here what I have done.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

val_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
x_test = np.load("../data/val_file.npy")
y_test = np.load("../data/val_label.npy")
val_gen.fit(x_test)

model = Sequential()
...
model_1.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model_1.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=sgd, 
               metrics=['acc'])

model.fit_generator(generate_batch_from_directory() # should give 1 image file and 1 label file
                    validation_data=val_gen.flow(x_test, 
                                                 y_test, 
                                                 batch_size=64),
                    validation_steps=32)
```

So here `generate_batch_from_directory()` should take `image_file_i.npy` and `label_file_i.npy` every time and optimise the weight until there is no batch left. Each image array in the .npy files has already been processed with augmentation, rotation and scaling. Each `.npy` file is properly mixed with data from class 1 and 0 (50/50).

If I append all the batch and create a big file such as:

```
X_train = np.append([image_file_1, ..., image_file_37])
y_train = np.append([label_file_1, ..., label_file_37])
```

It does not fit in the memory. Otherwise I could use `.flow()` to generate image sets to train the model.

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 16):

Finally I was able to solve that problem. But I had to go through source code and documentation of `keras.utils.Sequence` to build my own generator class. [This document](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) help a lot to understand how generator works in Kears. You can read more detail in my [kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/datapsycho/training-large-scale-data-with-keras-and-tf):

```
all_files_loc = "datapsycho/imglake/population/train/image_files/"
all_files = os.listdir(all_files_loc)

image_label_map = {
        "image_file_{}.npy".format(i+1): "label_file_{}.npy".format(i+1)
        for i in range(int(len(all_files)/2))}
partition = [item for item in all_files if "image_file" in item]

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, file_list):
        """Constructor can be expanded,
           with batch size, dimentation etc.
        """
        self.file_list = file_list
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
      'Take all batches in each iteration'
      return int(len(self.file_list))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
      'Get next batch'
      # Generate indexes of the batch
      indexes = self.indexes[index:(index+1)]

      # single file
      file_list_temp = [self.file_list[k] for k in indexes]

      # Set of X_train and y_train
      X, y = self.__data_generation(file_list_temp)

      return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
      'Updates indexes after each epoch'
      self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.file_list))

    def __data_generation(self, file_list_temp):
      'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
      data_loc = "datapsycho/imglake/population/train/image_files/"
      # Generate data
      for ID in file_list_temp:
          x_file_path = os.path.join(data_loc, ID)
          y_file_path = os.path.join(data_loc, image_label_map.get(ID))

          # Store sample
          X = np.load(x_file_path)

          # Store class
          y = np.load(y_file_path)

      return X, y

# ====================
# train set
# ====================
all_files_loc = "datapsycho/imglake/population/train/image_files/"
all_files = os.listdir(all_files_loc)

training_generator = DataGenerator(partition)
validation_generator = ValDataGenerator(val_partition) # work same as training generator

hst = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, 
                           epochs=200, 
                           validation_data=validation_generator,
                           use_multiprocessing=True,
                           max_queue_size=32)
```

Comment: This is a nice post. Could you also provide code for a customized `flow_from_directory` that is EXACTLY like the default keras `flow_from_directory` (so it allows you to do the augmentations `rotation_range`, `width_shift_range`, `shear_range`, ...) and additionally it allows to input images in `.npy` format?

Comment: Actually the numpy file I am using for training is already applied the autorotation and saved as .npy batch. `flow_from_directory` should be used when you what keras to do everything for you. If you already have `npy` files then `fit_generator` is preferable.