# Why my DataGenerator iterates on more data than the size of dataset and give IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I'm trying to implement a network with keras and tensorflow back-end, I'm using transfer learning model (VGG16), my dataset is a medical images dataset so instead of having only one image, I have a series of slices, so my dataset is organized in a folder and each serie is a np.array() with size (nb_slices,512,512,3). 
My dataset is composed by 1130 train samples and 120 valid samples, so I don't think that datas is the problem.
I tried to create a dataGenerator to load my image series in my model without a batch-size problem (I used this [Training a Keras model from batches of .npy files using generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788434/training-a-keras-model-from-batches-of-npy-files-using-generator) to make my generator class) , (and I reshaped my volumes with size (nb_slices, 224,224,3))
then I tried to use transfer learning, and custom a VGG16 network with 1 more convolution layer, MaxPooling, Flatten, Dense, Dropout and final Dense layer.

When I start training, it seems there is no problem, but at a moment it returns IndexError: list index out of range, and I saw that DataGenerator iterates more than the size of dataset but I don't know why...

Which part could cause it ?

Here is my DataGenerator

```py
INPUT_DIM = 224
MAX_PIXEL_VAL = 255
MEAN = 58.09
STDDEV = 49.73

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, file_list, labels, data_loc):
        self.listIDs = file_list
        self.labels = labels
        self.data_loc = data_loc
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        return int(len(self.listIDs))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        indexes = self.indexes[index:(index + 1)]
        list_IDS_temp = [self.listIDs[k] for k in indexes]
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDS_temp)
        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.listIDs))

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDS_temp):
        for ID in list_IDS_temp:
            vol = np.load(self.data_loc + ID + '.npy')
            nb_slices = vol.shape[0]
            pad = int((vol.shape[2] - INPUT_DIM) / 2)
            vol = vol[:, pad:-pad, pad:-pad]

            # standardize
            vol = (vol - np.min(vol)) / (np.max(vol) - np.min(vol)) * MAX_PIXEL_VAL

            # normalize
            vol = (vol - MEAN) / STDDEV

            # convert to RGB
            vol = np.stack((vol,) * 3, axis=3)

            y = np.empty(nb_slices, dtype=int)
            # y = self.labels[ID]
            for i in range(nb_slices):
                y[i] = self.labels[int(ID)]

        return vol, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)
```

and my model:

```py
train_set = DataGenerator(df_train['exams'].tolist(), df_train['labels'].tolist(), all_file_loc_train)

valid_set = DataGenerator(df_val['exams'].tolist(), df_val['labels'].tolist(), all_file_loc_val)

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))  # , input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers])
x = layer_dict['block2_pool'].output
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

custom_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=x)
for layer in custom_model.layers[:7]:
    layer.trainable = False

custom_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
                     metrics=["accuracy"])

results = custom_model.fit_generator(generator=train_set, validation_data=valid_set, epochs=50, verbose=2)
```

I expected accuracy around 80-90% of accuracy but it seems that something goes wrong in my DataGenerator and I don't know what. Please I need help...

Comment: What makes you think it is a problem? The only possible issue I see is that you are using binary_crossentropy for a softmax output, for which you should use categorical_crossentropy. binary_crossentropy should only be used with sigmoid output with one neuron.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thanks a lot ! :D I changed for categorical_crossentropy, I'm testing. Maybe I'm wrong but for me accuracy must increasing during training, if after only one epoch it's close to 1, it seems that there is overfitting or problem during training when the network is learning...

Comment: have you checked the output of your `DataGenerator`? Also is it validation or training accuracy?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi Yes I did it, I made a mistake in my DataGenerator, but for now I still have a problem, when the Datagenerator iterate on datas, I iterates on more datas than I had and at a moment it gives an error, I update my post now