# Is it possible for Keras to load tensors directly into VRAM and skip RAM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have a machine with very little RAM but it has a beefy GPU, is it possible to bypass RAM and load a `.npy` file directly into GPU?

For example,

```
model.fit(x=None, y=None)
```

What if my `X` is too big to fit in memory? Is there a mechanism where I can either load segment by segment from file system as it iterates through batches or simply pass the whole tensor to GPU? I think my first option can be answered by [Training a Keras model from batches of .npy files using generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788434/training-a-keras-model-from-batches-of-npy-files-using-generator)

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, it could be done. CreateFileMapping would allow to transfer data directly from disk to gpu. However, I don't believe tensorflow would support anything like that.